# ontouchend event somehow happening even if field is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a rangefield, which is normally disabled when the specific post was already rated. It is however possible to enable to rating with the click of a button so that the user can change the rating he has already done. Here is the code for it

```
<input class="form-control-range slider" id="ratingPost" onMouseUp="submit()" onTouchEnd="submit()" disabled="disabled" data-post-id="1" type="range" value="27" name="rating[score]" />
```

When the user is in desktop mode, the code is working just fine. The field is disabled and the user cannot click a range, so the onMouseUp thing is good. However, when the user is in device mode, it is possible to submit a new rating even tho it should be disabled.

How can I make the "disabled" attribute also disable the onTouchUp thing?
Thank you very much

Comment: Curious, why are you not using `onClick` for the submits? It should handle all your use cases.

Comment: @Anuj because when using the form, you click it and then drag the slider to the point where you wanted. If I use onclick then the value of the slider is submitted where the the user starts dragging, which I dont want ^^